# Laravel 5.2 can't read model property type from DB like as 'number' (with PHP7)

Tags: laravel, return-value, laravel-5

I've a weird problem with my local environment.

If I return with Laravel my model as json, every attributes are returned as string and not as numbers or booleans.

```
$j = Jobposition::find($id);
return $j;
```

If I use PHP 5.5 then the return-types are correct.

On my server it works fine with PHP7, so I think it's my local php setup.

Here is, how I compiled PHP 7.0.4:

```
./buildconf --force
env YACC=`brew --prefix bison27`/bin/bison ./configure  --prefix="/usr/local/opt/phpng"  --with-config-file-path="/usr/local/etc/phpng"  --enable-bcmath  --enable-calendar  --enable-exif  --enable-ftp  --enable-gd-native-ttf  --enable-gd-jis-conv  --enable-mbstring  --enable-pcntl  --enable-sysvmsg  --enable-sysvsem  --enable-sysvshm  --enable-wddx  --enable-zip  --enable-json  --with-bz2  --with-curl  --with-iconv  --with-freetype-dir=`brew --prefix freetype`  --with-gd  --with-gettext=`brew --prefix gettext`  --with-gmp  --with-jpeg-dir=`brew --prefix gd`  --with-mcrypt=`brew --prefix mcrypt`  --with-mysqli=`brew --prefix`/bin/mysql_config  --with-openssl  --with-pdo-mysql=`brew --prefix mariadb`  --with-png-dir=`brew --prefix gd`  --with-zlib=`brew --prefix zlib`

make -j`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max`

env INSTALL_ROOT=$PWD/phpng-pkg make install

pkgbuild  --root phpng-pkg  --identifier net.php.phpng  --version 7.0.4-dev  --ownership recommended  phpng-dev.pkg
```

According to following tutorial:
http://www.justinsilver.com/technology/install-php-7-0-phpng-on-mac-os-x/

My findings:
The encoding are working correctly - with json_encode it looks fine.

A workaround would be to use the $casts attribute in the model. But why defining it, if it should work out of the box (and I wanna know the problem ;-) )

Thanks
Stefan

**Update 29.02.2016:**
I was stupid, that I haven't checked it first. The problem has nothing to do with JSON!
The model is already filled false and is incorrect.

```
App\Job\Company\Jobposition {#994
     id: "1",
     title: "Maxime natus.",
     salary: "3181",
     contact: "Aglae.Shanahan@yahoo.com",
     published: "1",
     approved: "1",
}
```

Comment: Your return should look something like this: `return Response::json(array());`

Comment: @OliverQueen With Laravel 5.2 you don't need to return it with Response::json(...)

Answer (score 0):

It also occured to me (about a year ago), that my models types were not returned adequately when I switched to a dev server at my workplace.

The reason was that I had installed mysqlnd (PHP package) on my local VM, which helps PHP determine the proper variable type for a result set.

Without that, it's totally fine to have every type returned as a string.

I saw your configure call includes mysqli driver definitions. It might suffice not to define it as it's the default since 5.4 (that's at least what the docs say http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlnd.install.php)

This of course only fits, if we're talking about a MySQL database.

Comment: Hmm I've tried without defining the mysqli option, but it doesn't change.

Now I realize that I use mariadb locally - could be that the problem?

Comment: Different databases handle the connection to PHP differently. So it might be the "problem". In general it's always best to align your development environment to your production environment, so running Vagrant or a VM might be a better option than installing the components on your local machine.

Comment: Considering your setup, when you say PHP 5.5 runs correctly, what database is that version using? Also mariadb?